# How to check if .NET return type is NULL or not

Tags: .net, labview

I have a function called `AcqBuffer::FrameToDisplay` and it points to the address of image data. If image is not acquired then it is a null pointer.

From LabVIEW is there anyway to check if it is pointing to a null pointer or not ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your .NET refnum wire and create a constant. Compare against that with the Equals function. Constants of refnums are always Not A Refnum, and NULL is always Not A Refnum.